# Why the sudden jump of 100 points in my reputation ranking?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

(Tuesday, 30.Aug.2011, Taiyuan China time)
Until a day or so ago, my reputation ranking was 774. Then, suddenly, with no activity on my part, it is 874, exactly 100 points higher. What happened?

Comment: One way this can happen is by your logging into a second  StackExchange site for the first time. Do you think it might be that?

Comment: A check of your account tab: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/2344/mike-jones?tab=accounts says this is your only account with rep $\geq 200$; you might want to visit http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation to see how your rep went up.

Comment: @Dylan Moreland: Yes, I signed up with Meta Stack Overflow. So, is such bumping up of rep in another site a bug, or not? Thanks.

Comment: @Mike I think this is by design. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96062/account-association-bug-or-feature/96064#96064) on the SO meta. It happened to me when I signed up for the [TeX SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See also [+100 rep for account association — what are the conditions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2204)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design. See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) where the feature is announced, and [the official answer on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238) (in the "additionally" section). As both resources mention, *only one* of the two accounts you are associating needs to have $\geq200$ reputation.

Also, if you go to https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation to audit your reputation, I am pretty sure the association bonus appears in the line

```
 rep from bonuses:
```

although I am not sure what other bonuses exist... perhaps any bounties you've earned are included in this row as well.

By the way, I performed a recalc on your account (you can do this too using the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button at the bottom of https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation) and that bumped it to 885. I'm afraid there's no good way of figuring out where the net difference of 11 points came from; generally, your "displayed" reputation can fall out of line with your "real" reputation, and the reputation recalc is just a manual update of  the "displayed" reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've upvoted and accepted your excellent answer.

Comment: I'm glad to help!